# Windows CE SDK for Visual Studio 2008

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile, windows-ce

I am new to Windows CE programming.

I have Visual Studio 2008 and Visual Studio 2005. I have found the following SDK for Windows Mobile

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=06111A3A-A651-4745-88EF-3D48091A390B&displaylang=en

Please help me in deciding if this is the correct one, or please feel free to redirect me the correct one

Thanks in advance
Sujay

Answer (score 12):

If you are targetting a Windows CE device (and not Windows Mobile), then each device has it's own specific SDK. If you are not using a device specific functionality, you create a C# for Windows CE 5.0 application and it will work on every Windows CE device that has the .Net component included in the image.
Don't mix Windows CE and Windows Mobile. Windows Mobile 5-6.5 is based on Windows CE 5.0, but has a standard SDK (different SDK's for different versions of the Windows Mobile at use). Windows CE, as I mentioned, is used in specific solutions and you should get the SDK form the OEM.

Answer (score 3):

If you need a Windows CE Emulator get it here
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/thankyou.aspx?familyId=a120e012-ca31-4be9-a3bf-b9bf4f64ce72&displayLang=en

and to setup the Emulator look at this guide http://www.hpc.net/chat.asp?ObjectID=97662

Edit: The hpc.net link is now dead so here is what was found on the page using the wayback machine. https://web.archive.org/web/20070428121320/http://www.hpc.net/chat.asp?ObjectID=97662

Connecting the CE 5.0 Emulator to VS2005

1. This uses the network method and saves the emulator state. It does not use activesync, communications ports or a null modem cable.

   Start the emulator using a shortcut command that is something like this:

   "C:\Program Files\Windows CE 5.0 Emulator\Emulator_500.exe" nk.cem
   /video 640x480x16
   /Ethernet virtualswitch
   /sharedfolder "C:\CE5SharedFolder"

   The shared folder appears on the emulator as \My Device\Storage Card. Using the shared folder, copy the following files to the \My Device\Windows\ folder on the emulator. These files are located on the host at \Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\CoreCon\1.0\Target\wce400\x86, or similar

   - Clientshutdown.exe
   - ConmanClient2.exe
   - CMaccept.exe
   - eDbgTL.dll
   - TcpConnectionA.dll
2. Select Emulator -> Start Menu -> run -> \Windows\conmanclient2.exe.
3. Get the IP address of the emulator by double-clicking on the T networking symbol bottom left. If it has no ip address try installing Microsoft Loopback Adapter on the host, check for Virtual Machine Network Services, or other host networking hacks. (This is the difficult bit).
4. To check that the emulator is responding, on the host type Ping at a DOS prompt.
5. To get "Save State" working on the emulator, shut down the emulator using the "Save State" option. Then navigate to Host -> My Documents -> My Virtual Machines
6. The saved state is in the folder that is named with a curly brackets string similar to {06A8A448-EB8B-4E0B-8A88-451412A10C66} say, and known as a GUID. Attempt to rename this folder so that you can highlight and copy the GUID string itself (not the folder).
7. Then add an option, which is similar to /vmid {06A8A448-EB8B-4E0B-8A88-451412A10C66}, to the emulator shortcut command above.
8. The shortcut should now start the emulator from its saved state. It is a good idea to back up the saved state folder.
9. On the host select Visual Studio 2005 -> Tools -> Options -> Device Tools -> Devices
10. Then select Windows CE 5.0 Device -> Properties -> Configure
11. In the "Configure TCP/IP Transport" dialog box, select "Use specific IP address", and then type the emulator IP address you found above.
12. Close the dialog boxes.
13. Select Emulator -> Start -> run -> \Windows\cMaccept.exe and connect to the emulator from VS2005 within three minutes.
14. Run your application from Start Debugging in VS2005 and VS2005 should deploy the two cab files nectcfv2.wce5.x86.cab and system_SR_enu.cab first (this may take some time), and then your application.
15. Close your application in the emulator (I've had trouble using the Stop button on the host).
16. Shut down the emulator using the "Save State" option.
17. You may need to re-run cMaccept each time you restart the emulator or VS2005, but the cab files should not need to deploy again, and the emulator ip address should remain the same.
18. To avoid cMaccept navigate host -> programs -> Microsoft Visual Studio 2005 -> Visual Studio Remote Tools -> Remote Registry Editor
19. In the "Select a Windows Device" dialog box that appears highlight the "Windows CE 5.0 Device" option
20. In the emulator run cMaccept and then immediately click OK in the Remote Registry Editor
21. Highlight Windows CE 5.0 -> HKLM -> System
22. Right click in the right hand pane and select New DWORD value.
23. In the name field type (exactly and without the quotes) "CoreConOverrideSecurity" and set its value to 1
24. Close the editor. Shut down the emulator with Save State.

Comment: The hpc.net link is dead. :(

Answer (score 0):

First off, Sujay, I'll assume you didn't mean Windows CE explicitly.  I'll assume you meant programming for handheld devices running a Microsoft operating system.  CE hasn't been used for five or six years.  The devices are all running Windows Mobile.  6.5 is the most popular now.

You do not need an SDK to program for Windows Mobile in Visual Studio.  It is already baked in.  If you want to get the latest tools to develop on Windows Mobile 6, then yes, the [location](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=06111a3a-a651-4745-88ef-3d48091a390b&DisplayLang=en) you specified is perfect.

Here's another great place to get high-level info: [Windows Mobile Development Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/windowsmobile)

Comment: Well, there are still some guys who uses Wince for their devices. So I need to create an application that shall run on Win CE. How can I acheive that.

Comment: Windows CE is still used. But, it is used in solution specific devices usually.

Comment: +1 for point out WinCE is in use. Infact we are using it for devices that works with less storage like 64/128 MB. Mind you again not GB its MB ;)

Comment: Devices are still being produced from major manufacturers with Windows CE. It's not dead. More importantly, WinCE isn't saddled with some of the productivity-crippling features of Windows Mobile.

Comment: @Rap, the Windows Mobile link is dead. :(

Comment: @jp2code Oh my gosh, so is Windows Mobile, VS2008, and all devices that they run on.  ;-)  This post is over six years old, so no wonder, right? I tried to update my link but I can't find anything current from M$.

Comment: Understood. We have a new customer that uses old Windows CE Kiosks. I've got to brush up on my old skills. :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use C# and create smartdevice project,
and use c# for making apps,use unmanaged code by improting DLL's..

for more sample just see "Program Files\Windows Mobile 6 SDK\Samples\PocketPC\CPP"
here u get some samples.