# is it possible to compile code for WinCE platform through VisualStudio in WIndows?

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I need to compile code written in Visual studio 2008 in Windows XP for WinCE mobile platform.
How to do it in Visual studio 2008 by changing target platform settings ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440537/windows-ce-sdk-for-visual-studio-2008

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Visual Studio 2008 see [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t(v=VS.90).aspx) as a starting point.

For C++ [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b20d48w3(v=VS.90).aspx) is the index page and [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5fc53wa(v=VS.90).aspx) tells you how to build and debug. There are a fair number of steps in terms of compiler options and what additional files you need so I won't quote them here.

Comment: Not mentioned by others, but you get a device emulator too. I found it quite straightforward.

Comment: I am unable to access the links

Comment: @bjskishore123 - odd the actual address of the first page is http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa69he4t(v=VS.90).aspx so you can copy and paste into your browser to see if that works.