# Howto use debugger on WinCE5 device with VS2008 (Win7)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, windows-ce

I am trying to debug an application for WinCE devices. I got VS2008 installed on my machine (next to VS2010) but I cannot debug in emulator nor on the devices. I searched some time now but can anyone explain how to configure this properly or give a *good* link?

When using debugger it complains that `AppName\AppName.exe` was not found on the device. When setting smart device to `Windows CE` to connect to my device it simply says that it cannot connect after some time.

I do not have ActiveSync installed as it is not available for Win7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this managed code or native code?  If native, what processor architecture (ARM, x86, etc) ? For native code you need to at least have an SDK installed with the matching architecture - the exact SDK though doesn't actually matter.

To make a debugger connection, try copying the corecon bits (conmanclient2.exe, cmaccept.exe, etc) to the device an manually running that, then connecting to the IP address.  This works for both managed and native apps and is way more reliable than trying to use the WMDC/AS pipe.  [This article covers it](http://nicolasbesson.blogspot.com/2008/02/smart-device-deployment-and-debugging.html) - it's for 2005, but the process in VS08 is identical.

Comment: I was interrupted with other projects but got back to it today. I got the CoreCon-method to work. Have to do several VS-restarts after changing some settings or to re-establish the connection after some fixing but it works and this is so much better than writing the code blind with debugging purposes. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

For Vista and later use Windows Mobile Device Center:

[WMDC for 32-bit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5784)
[WMDC for 64-bit](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=3182)

After installing the approriate version plug in your device and it should connect.

If you want to debug a managed process that's already running you have to set a registry flag on the device before running the process.
[How to: Attach to Managed Device Processes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1ksfbk7%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Hope that helps

Comment: WMDC is already installed and connected to the device. I used it to install apps on it and share my network. It got the feeling that VS2008 does not recognize it.

Comment: Digging a bit deeper I found http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440537/windows-ce-sdk-for-visual-studio-2008 where the top answer explains that you need the specific SDK from the OEM. For instance if it's a Motorola/Symbol product you get the Motorola EMDK for C, .NET or Java. I never reflected over it since I've only ever used Motorola products and I have their EMDK installed.